# Are ability scores restored daily even while still under an affliction?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I'm trying to better understand afflictions and I was wondering if, for example;

Someone gets *Ghoul Fever*.  If they fail the save then they take 1d3 Con and 1d3 Dex damage.

The next day, would they regain 1 point in each of those despite still being diseased?  Or do you have to cure yourself first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My instinctive answer to this was no, but after looking it over, I would say that, yes, in general you do still heal stats while diseased. Some specific exceptions exist, like [Mummy Rot](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/monsters/mummy.html#_mummy), which prevents you from healing while under its effects.

Comment: Yeah at first I would have said no, but then as I read it I became unsure.  Thanks for the input